# Teapot Riddle (No. 34) Strikes Again!

Tags: riddle, word

I got inspired from @[Jannis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52327/jannis) and @[user477343](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/42452/user477343) (you should really start using a name, lol) for making amazing teapot riddles. Be sure to check their riddles as well

> > **RULES :**
>
> I have one word which has several (2 or more) meanings
>
> Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
>
> Try to figure out the word with my hints.
>
> > **Hint 1 :**
>
> The first teapot can be loud
>
> While the second will love you
>
> > **Hint 2 :**
>
> My first teapot can help you in hot conditions
>
> The second can *sometimes* be violent, perhaps brutal

```
WILL ADD MORE HINTS IN THE FUTURE
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Fan

The first teapot can be loud

> **Fan** - an apparatus with rotating blades that creates a current of air, these can be quite loud

While the second will love you

> **Fan** - a person who has a strong interest in or admiration for a particular person or thing.

My first teapot can help you in hot conditions

> Fans can be used to keep you cool

The second can sometimes be violent, perhaps brutal

> Especially sports fans can be violent when things are not going their way.

Comment: Oh come on! You answered one of my riddles again and so quickly :D

Comment: @KevinL **hexomino**'s good; there's a reason for that >30k reputation. But nice riddle, too. I could not solve it, so I am glad someone did :P

Answer (score 0):

Why isn't the correct answer marked yet? it just bores people when they see an answered puzzle but clicking (which also increases the views on) the puzzle makes them realize that it is already answered when they look at the comments. This is purely bad practice I must say - and an unfair means to get more views.
PS: I can't yet comment due to lack of reputation points on this site.

Comment: Romeo, welcome to Puzzling.SE! I'm sorry to hear that you feel that way. The reasoning for some puzzle creators to leave the puzzle unmarked for a 24 hour period is (a) to get more views on the puzzle; but more importantly (b) if there is another puzzler out there with an answer that fits the puzzle better than the intended answer, the 24 hour period gives them time to identify this better answer if it exists. I hope this helps!

Comment: @El-Guest Exactly what I wanted to say XD